# Any support for MongoDB?

Tags: database

Does anyone know, if craft gets support for MongoDB in the near future? Or is any solution out there for using MongoDB? This would be awesome. :)

Kind regards
Ron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the near, probably not in the long and a pretty slim chance in the very long-term future.

We'll add support for additional relational databases (MSSQL, SQLite PostgreSQL, Oracle) long before a NoSQL solution and they will each bring their own level of additional support and challenges.